# How to merge and dissolve adjacent polygons and sum up their attributes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have many polygons that are adjacent to each other, and others overlap slightly. I need to merge them and sum up their attribute (Area per class). I attach an image of my problem (Screenshot of my merged polygons. Each color represents a landcover class)

I am able to merge the polygons using the function "merge Layers" from the MMQGIS plugin. But the adjancent polygons of the same type are not dissolved, nor their Area summed up.

I tried already using the function Dissolve (per Area) and doesn´t work either.

I am beginner in QGIS. I am working in QGIS 2.12.3 in a PC.

[image: Screenshot of my polygons merged. Each color represent a landcover class]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @Ed Rollason I used the Topology checker to understand where was my problem.

Ok, as I said, my layers overlap. But they overlap like a zipper (one on top of each other). After trying many tools (union, difference, merge, dissolve) without success, I found a video that explains the v.clean tool of the Process Toolbox.

In QGIS 2.12.3, go to Processing > Toolbox > GRASS Commands > Vector. I tried v.clean tool like in the video, but I had some geometry errors. Therefore, I used v.dissolve, tolerance = 1 and afterwards the Dissolve tool for a final clean up of the image.

Regarding the attributes, I have the total area of each class.

Link to the video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1ChPvsC4bU

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to dissolve based on the landcover attribute rather than area.

[image: The dissolve box allows you to specify a field in the attribute table field of shared values]

This will dissolve adjacent polygons which share an attribute.

You can then calculate the area of the polygons in the attribute table using the field calculator.

Comment: thank you for your help. I tried that one already but the output file is just empty. When I open the attribute table there is nothing in it. I used a merged file as an input file, where all the polygons are merged into one, but the attributes are preserved.

Comment: It might be that it's having issues with the topology of the shapefile after your merge; for example invalid geometries.  You could try the QGIS topology checker (http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html) or sometimes importing a file into GRASS and back again can solve some issues like this - example here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163820/error-in-merging-2-shape-files-of-different-geometry-types/163831#163831

Comment: @EdRollanson I checked the Topography and seems that there is no problem. However, I managed to split the vector into each class and dissolve each. The problem now is that I have only one feature in the Attribute Table. The Dissolve function summed up the area of the whole vector file... and I need the area per polygon.

Comment: @EdRollanson (correction) I checked the Topography again and there are overlapping parts of my polygons. How to get rid of this?

Comment: I'm guessing by your answer below you solved this one.  If it worked mark it as a correct answer.