# Merging two linestrings gives Geometry type error in MMQGIS?

Tags: merge, line, linestring, polyline-creation, mmqgis

I am trying to merge two linestrings/Lines/Polylines (not sure actually how I can see the difference whether my layer is a Linestring/Line or Polyline and googling didn't really brought clarification).

When I try to merge them (I tried with the MMQGIS 'Merge layers' function as well as with 'Data management Tools' -> 'Merge Shapefiles to one') I get an error saying that the geometry types need to be the same.

This is what I've tried so far:

1. I tried the 'Multiparts to Singleparts' option on both of them and tried to merge them
2. I tried to save both of them with the LineString as geometry type and with the Z-dimension bocks ticked off and merging the results
3. I tried to export them as a CSV and manuallymerging the data in one excel document that I tried to upload again (failed since it can't find coordinates)

(these three are worked out here: [Error in merging 2 shape files of different geometry types](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163820/error-in-merging-2-shape-files-of-different-geometry-types?rq=1))
 4. Finally I tried the Dissolve tool after which I tried to merge the result.

All of this without result. Probably I'm just overlooking something very easy. I hope someone can shine his/her light on this and help me out with it. I attach a photo of the Two Linestrings as well as their Attribute Table.

[image: printscreen]

[image: attributetable]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since MMQGIS fails because ***"the geometry types need to be the same"***, you may try to convert all the layers to lines before running the plugin.

It could help using the **Convert geometry type** algorithm from the Processing Toolbox (the name is self-explanatory). You may try to convert both layers to `LineString`, so they will be of the same geometry type.

As an additional test, you may also select a layer from the Layers Panel and then run this simple code from the **Python Console**:

```py
layer=iface.activeLayer()
print layer.wkbType()
```

This will print a number which defines the geometry type of your layer: if the `print` returns `2`, your layer is a Linestring; if the `print` returns `5`, the layer is a MultiLineString (you may try to run the above code before and after the execution of the algorithm for seeing the difference).

---

You may find some useful information about the formal definition of Linestring and MultiLineString from [this](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=25355) document of the [OGC® Standards](http://www.opengeospatial.org/docs/is) (pp. 22-25).

Comment: I tried converting the geometry type to Linestrings through "Convert geometry type" as you proposed, but again without success. When running the code on the Python Console it returned the value 2 for one layer and the value -2147483646 for the other. (I added a screenshot of this to the initial question)

Comment: @mathiasdhaen that's weird, I never saw that value :) You may do another attempt by directly running the **Merge vector layers** SAGA tool from Processing

Comment: @mathiasdhaen Perhaps there is some corruption in the file returning the weird value. Try creating a new shapefile and copy / paste the features in the new file.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to this problem. I first made sure both layers were a Linestring through "Convert Geometry Type", saved both linestrings as a KML and merged them with the MMQGIS option, after which I saved it again as a Shapefile.